# Deploy Modern UI App

Tags: windows-8.1, mdm, microsoft-intune

1. I have enrolled my devices with Windows Intune and Install Corporate Portal to them.
2. I have added to InTune some Windows Store App, MS Corporate Portal appx and my own application appx.
3. When I am launching the Corporate Portal on my devices I can see Windows Store App and Corporate Portal appx.  But I cannot see my own application appx.

Why?  I can sudgest that the reason of this is that I use untrusted certificate (wich was generated by VS) to sign my application. I am right? Do I need to by trusted Symantec certificate to deploy my own application by Windows InTune and Corporate Portal?

May be the is some way to use self-signed certificate to deploy my application?

Another question: is it enough to have Symantec certificate to deploy my application or do I need something else? For example, sideloading key.